# Ignoring &#160; when parsing with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm parsing html table in c# using Html Agility Pack that contains non-breaking space.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(page);
```

Where page is string containing table with special characters `&#160;` within text.

```
<td>&#160;test</td>
<td>number =&#160;123&#160;</td>
```

Using `SelectSingleNode(".//td").InnerText` will contains this special characters but i want to ignore them.

Is there some elegant way to ignore this (with or without help of Html Agility Pack) without modifying source table?

Comment: Can't you just remove the characters in the text returned by `InnerText`, using `string.Replace`?

Comment: What does "ignore" mean here? Normally, I would expect an "ignored" character to have no effect, but that would mean that your second table cell contains "number =123", while you probably do want a space between "=" and "123".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx)

```
string foo = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("Special char: &#160;");
```

Will give you a string:

> Special char:

Answer (score 0):

The "Special Character" non-breaking-space of which you speak is a valid character which can perfectly legitimately appear in text, just as "fancy quotes", em-dash etc can.

Often we want to treat certain characters as being equivalent.

- So you might want to treat an em-dash, en-dash and minus sign/dash as
  being the same.
- Or fancy quotes as the same as straight quotes.
- Or   the non-breaking-space as an ordinary space.

However this is not something HTML Agility pack can help with. You need to use something like string.Replace or your own canonicalization function to do this.

I would suggest something like:

```
static string CleanupStringForMyApp(string s){
    // replace characters with their equivalents
    s = s.Replace(string.FromCharCode(160), " ");
    // Add any more replacements you want to do here
    return s;
}
```